# Receiving UDP packets with wrong checksum in Python

Tags: python, udp, checksum

I am running a server application on a PC which receives UDP packets from a client. The UDP packets are received (verified in WireShark), but include the wrong checksum. I have no control over the client and need to be able to receive these packets in Python. The following code doesn't see the packets:

```
UDPSock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPSock.bind(addr)

while 1:
    data,addr = UDPSock.recvfrom(buf)
    if not data:
        print "Client has exited!"
        break
    else:
        print "\nReceived message '", data,"'"

UDPSock.close()
```

Anyway in Python I can receive malformed UDP packets?

Comment: Do you know the reason the checksum is wrong?  I mean that is suppose to be handled by the UDP client.  The code you posted does not see the packets because its being thrown out likely by the underline network device, because the checksum is wrong, resolve that problem.

Comment: How do you KNOW the checksum is wrong? Wireshark running on the _sending_ system will often (almost always, nowadays) report bad checksums because checksum calculation is offloaded to the adapter and the driver doesn't bother to do the checksums.  This is a well-known pseudo-problem.  However, if you're getting bad checksums on the _receiving_ system, that's another issue.

Comment: If you're really getting bad checksums then we're going to need to know the physical hardware characteristics at both ends and along the path between the two systems.

Comment: The client is a FPGA with a PHY chip. All MAC layer is done on the FPGA. I don't have the source code for the FPGA, so don't have control over it. I assume the checksum is incorrect, because checksum validation is turned off in Wireshark and it's able to receive the packets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

I used the [pycap](http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/) library in combination with [dpkt](http://code.google.com/p/dpkt/). The pycap module is outdated, for older versions of Python, but in the "Issues" someone posted updated binaries.